# UIScrollView change position base on time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a UIScrollView but I want to animate the scrollview to show a different view of the scroll view every 10 seconds. For what I have found this method may help:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

But any of you knows if is a way implement the change of scrollview base on time?

Comment: Have you looked at the `NSTimer` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
target:self
selector:@selector(updateScrollPosition:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];
```

then inside `updateScrollPosition` you can update the offset of your scrollView accordingly.

```
-(void)updateScrollPosition{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
    // where contentOffset is the custom CGPoint 
    // where you want your scrollView to scroll after every 10 sec
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to show the dots in the scrollview?